# How to read from input stream for certain time?

Tags: java, concurrency, distributed-computing, race-condition, concurrent.futures

I have to read lines from InputStream during certain time and return the lines that I read in a List. In my current solution I am not sure if it is the best way to interrupt a thread, because sometimes after the return some orders are added, and other times not.

This is my current solution.

```
InputStream source;
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public OrderStreamReader(InputStream source, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.source = source;
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}

public List<OrderStream> get( Duration maxTime) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    ReaderOrdersStream readerOrder = new ReaderOrdersStream();
    Future future = executor.submit(readerOrder::run);

    try {
        future.get(maxTime.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    return readerOrder.orders;
}

private class ReaderOrdersStream {
    private List<OrderStream> orders = new LinkedList<>();
    

    public void run() {
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(source))) {
            String rawOrder;
            while ((rawOrder = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                var currentOrder = objectMapper.readValue(rawOrder, OrderStream.class);
                if (Thread.interrupted()) break;
                orders.add(currentOrder);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }`
```

Avoid extra added orders after return.

Comment: To format your text as code, indent *all* lines by four spaces, or else nest in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

### No need for threading here

If you launch a task in a background thread, and then immediately wait for results, there is no point in using that other thread at all. You might as well perform the task in the first thread.

By the way, you do not correctly handle shutting down an executor service. See the boilerplate code given to you in `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` method in the Javadoc for [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). In Java 19+, `ExecutorService` is [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), so you can make convenient use of try-with-resources syntax to automatically close the executor service.

### Check elapsed time as each line imports

Without threading, just check elapsed time on every loop while reading your input stream.

To get elapsed time, you could count nanoseconds that have passed by calling `System.nanoTime`. But the ever-increasing count of nanos returned by that call can be reset when reading the limit of a `long`. How long until that limit is reached is undefined, so I would not rely upon this in production code.

#### `Instant.now` & `Duration`

A better way to get elapsed time, if a resolution of microseconds suffices, is to use `Instant` class with its `Instant.now()` method to capture the current moment as a date-time seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. Use `Duration` class to represent a span-of-time not attached to the timeline.

```java
record Person( String firstName , String lastName ) { }
ArrayList < Person > persons = new ArrayList <> ( );
Duration maxTime = Duration.ofMillis ( 10 );
InputStream inputStream = null;

Instant start = Instant.now ( );
try (
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = …
)
{
    String line;
    while ( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine ( ) ) != null )
    {
        // Time limit not yet expired, so process another line.
        String[] parts = line.split ( "," );
        String firstName = parts[ 0 ];
        String lastName = parts[ 1 ];
        Person person = new Person ( firstName , lastName );
        persons.add ( person );

        // Check to see if exceeding our time limit.
        Duration elapsed = Duration.between ( start , Instant.now ( ) );
        if ( elapsed.toNanos ( ) > maxTime.toNanos ( ) ) break;  // If we have exceeded our time limit, break out of this `while`` loop.
    }
} catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException ( e );
}
```

Comment: When you end up comparing nanoseconds anyway, use `System.nanoTime()` in the first place. Before the loop: `long maxTime = Duration.ofMillis(10).toNanos(), start = System.nanoTime();` Inside the loop: `if(System.nanoTime() - start > maxTime) break;`

Comment: It seems good, but there is a problem because the buffer reader is waiting for the next string, if this string comes after 10 mins, we will be stopped in this line `while ( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine ( ) ) != null )`

Comment: @JoeGilbert If you are asking how to interrupt an `InputStream` or `BufferedReader` that is taking too long, post a Question on that exact topic.

Comment: @BasilBourque yes but this is my question how to read for a specific time an InputStream. I don't want to interrupt if it is taking too long, I want to interrupt at this specific time. If the thread is reading I need to leave that and continue with the next calculations, with the lines that the thread read at that moment, instead of keeping that thread blocked.